# Sharing an image from javascript SDK does not load the image?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, share, feed

Here is the very simple code:

```
            var obj = {
                method: "feed",
                link: share_url,
                picture: share_url,
                name: "test name",
                caption: "test caption",
                description: "Using Dialogs to interact with users."
            };
            function callback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
            FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

The share_url is something like this:

http://www.majorforms.com/thumbnail.php?width=1200&height=1200&image=1033/4f/4f313dee7641ba3add3ac080f451277a9af9f0cc.jpg

The thing is that the post is written on my wall, but the image is not there! Even though I have given the same URL for "link" and "picture". Why is that?

Comment: It might be because you are providing a really really large image... It's funny because you are calling a thumbnail script but giving it 1200x1200px :P Try supplying a smaller image. Facebook might just see the image size and ignore it...

Comment: All right, I gave this to picture:

http://www.majorforms.com/thumbnail.php?width=200&height=200&image=1033/4f/4f313dee7641ba3add3ac080f451277a9af9f0cc.jpg

And this to link:

http://www.majorforms.com/thumbnail.php?width=1200&height=1200&image=1033/4f/4f313dee7641ba3add3ac080f451277a9af9f0cc.jpg

but it still does not work. I have tried even smaller sizes. It seems that the problem is not with the size.

Comment: Also tried to share an HTML page instead of an image but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer. If I leave out the picture parameter, then everything works! E.g.

```
        var obj = {
            method: "feed",
            link: share_url,
            name: "test name",
            caption: "test caption",
            description: "Using Dialogs to interact with users."
        };
        function callback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

I don't know why, but this is how it is.